# The function that shall have no name

Tags: haskell

The following code at http://ideone.com/q7fWij compiles successfully, but when I attempt to even name the function:

```
(\fn (D x) -> f fn x)
```

by say:

```
h = (\fn (D x) -> f fn x)
```

I get a compile error:

```
SO-30447787.hs:51:19:
    Couldn't match expected type `t1' with actual type `String'
      `t1' is untouchable
        inside the constraints (Constraints t2 a)
        bound by a pattern with constructor
                   D :: forall t a. (Constraints t a) => a -> D t,
                 in a lambda abstraction
        at SO-30447787.hs:51:11-13
      `t1' is a rigid type variable bound by
           the inferred type of h :: t -> D t2 -> t1
           at SO-30447787.hs:51:1
    Relevant bindings include
      h :: t -> D t2 -> t1
        (bound at SO-30447787.hs:51:1)
    In the expression: f fn x
    In the expression: (\ fn (D x) -> f fn x)
```

Is there a way to name this poor function, or is it forever destined for a life of anonymity?

(By the way, what I'm playing around with is a class that searches up a tree for a function to call).

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}
{-# LANGUAGE UndecidableInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverlappingInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}

import GHC.Exts (Constraint)

type family Parent a

class C a b where
  f :: b -> a -> String

instance (C (Parent a) b) => C a b where
  f _ _ = f (undefined :: b) (undefined :: Parent a) 

data A1 = A1
data A2 = A2
data A3 = A3
data A4 = A4

type instance Parent A2 = A1
type instance Parent A3 = A2
type instance Parent A4 = A3

data F1 = F1
data F3 = F3

instance C A1 F1 where
  f _ _ = "F1"

instance C A3 F3 where
  f _ _ = "F3"

type family Constraints t a :: Constraint

data D t = forall a. (Constraints t a) => D a

type instance Constraints A1 a = (C a F1)
type instance Constraints A2 a = (C a F1, C a F3)
type instance Constraints A3 a = (C a F1, C a F3)
type instance Constraints A4 a = (C a F1, C a F3)

main = 
  do
--    let h = (\fn (D x) -> f fn x)
    putStrLn (f F1 A1)
    putStrLn (f F1 A2)
    putStrLn (f F1 A3)
    putStrLn (f F1 A4)
    putStrLn (f F3 A3)
    putStrLn (f F3 A4)
    putStrLn $ (\fn (D x) -> f fn x) F1 ((D A1) :: D A1)
    putStrLn $ (\fn (D x) -> f fn x) F1 ((D A2) :: D A1)
    putStrLn $ (\fn (D x) -> f fn x) F3 ((D A3) :: D A2)
```

Comment: How on earth did you make a dry Haskell problem into such an entertaining read?

Answer (score 1):

If you give a type signature to `h`, then that takes care of your immediate problem:

```
h :: b -> D a -> String
h = \fn (D x) -> f fn x
```

However, this just highlights a more fundamental problem: that in general, there's nothing prohibiting the reflexive and the `Parent` case from overlapping with each other:

```
Overlapping instances for C (Parent a1) b arising from a use of `f'
Matching instances:
  instance [overlap ok] C (Parent a) b => C a b
    -- Defined at SO-30447787.hs:21:10
  instance [overlap ok] C A3 F3
    -- Defined at SO-30447787.hs:46:10
  instance [overlap ok] C A1 F1
    -- Defined at SO-30447787.hs:43:10
(The choice depends on the instantiation of `b, a1'
 To pick the first instance above, use IncoherentInstances
 when compiling the other instance declarations)
In the expression: f fn x
In the expression: \ fn (D x) -> f fn x
In an equation for `h': h = \ fn (D x) -> f fn x
```

What you really want is to use the instance stored in the `D` constructor. I'm not sure yet how to express that in Haskell (or if it's expressible at all).

One thing that I hoped would work is to use [`Data.Constraint.Dict`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints/docs/Data-Constraint.html) to reify the instance dictionary stored in `D`:

```
import Data.Constraint

data D t = forall a. D (Dict (Constraints t a)) a

h :: b -> D a -> String
h fn (D d@Dict x) = f fn x
```

but of course there's still nothing connecting the usage of `f` on the right-hand side to `d` on the left-hand side, so it still suffers from the same problem.

UPDATE:

I've realized that there's nothing forcing `C a t` to follow from `Constraints t a` in general (nothing prevents me from adding `type instance Constraints A5 a = ()`), so just because we have `Dict :: Dict (Constraints t a)` in scope, it's not going to be picked up for the `C a b` constraint imposed by calling `f`. You need to completely rethink what you're *actually* (as in, in your real use case, not the minimal reproduction case here) trying to do.

Comment: I get the same error irregardless of the type signature. I'm not sure how it helps (and I'm not sure it's correct anyway).

Comment: http://ideone.com/mtuYnK

That uses GHC 7.6. I get the same error with the same code in GHC 7.10.1

Comment: Now one of us is just getting confused. The error message in your link is exactly the one I included in my answer -- it points to the deeper problem of overlapping instances. If you don't give a type signature to the definition of `h`, you get the error I've added as an edit to your original question. These are two completely different type errors.

Comment: Can you link to full code that compiles with the type signature. I've added your type signature and I can't get it to compile (and I've tried my own variations also)

Comment: Please read my answer again. It does *not* compile because of the overlapping instances. Those are a genuine (and orthogonal) problem.

Comment: I have the overlapping instance extension selected. And without "h" defined, it compiles fine and runs, despite the overlapping instances, so why are they causing the problem?

Comment: Maybe you should add a new question about the overlapping/incoherent instances. Note how your program has `OverlappingInstances` turned on, but not `IncoherentInstances`. Have you read the details of the error message? Also, without `h` defined, all of its occurances are completely monomorphic so the issue does not apply at all.

Comment: I still don't understand how `f x` can be valid, but `g = f`, `g x` is not. That seems bizarre. That's the crux of my question.

Comment: Have you picked up my point about the other occurrences being monomorphic? If you define `g = E`, you have to give `g` a sufficiently polymorphic type; whereas if you happen to use `E` in several contexts, all of them monomorphic, then I'm not even sure it's guaranteed there's a polymorphic type that encompasses all of the monomorphic types you can possibly use `E` at.

Comment: I have, kind of, but obviously not completely. But why can't `h` just delay selecting the instance until it's called. Like if I write `myAdd :: (Num a) => a -> a -> a` myAdd itself doesn't need to know the instance until it's actually called with floats or ints or whatever.

Comment: I think I've figured out the underlying problem -- we need to find a way to tell `f fn x` to pick the dictionary from `D`, not from out of thin air based on `a` and `b`. Let me see if I can do that. Maybe something involving [instance dictionary reification](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints-0.4.1.3/docs/Data-Constraint.html#g:2)...

Comment: I'll drop you a bounty for a nice answer, as I'm really interested in what I can learn from this.